# Boost implementation of dynamic mersenne twister generation

Tags: c++, boost, random

For creating a thread safe mersenne twister there is a technique for seeding multiple twisters from a single seed:
http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/DC/dgene.pdf

There is a C++ implementation of this which by the Authors' own admission is buggy
http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/DC/dc.html

There is also a Fortran one somewhere.

Has anyone seen one in action that builds on `Boost::random`?  That would be the most useful...

Comment: MT is automatically thread-safe or not possibly threadsafe at all, depening on how you look at it. It will not crash if accessed concurrently, but the sequence of numbers is no longer reproduceable. It is still pseudorandom, though. MT is a "simple" lagged fibonacci generator where the lag is quite big. The only thing that can conceivably go wrong is updating the pointer into the state array, and inconsistenly updating state. Serious performance loss due to false sharing is a much more severe concern, since several threads pulling random numbers will concurrently modify the same cache lines.

Comment: The best is not to try to use the same MT with different threads, really. Even if you use a heavyweight mutex to protect it, several threads pulling random numbers will still influence each other's sequence in an unknown manner (since every read is also a write in a lagged generator), making the sequence unreproducable (which is usually what one still wants -- normally you want "random" and apparently uncorrelated results, but given the same seed, the total outcome should still be reproduceable, identical).

Comment: The paper is about creating different instances of MT, not just with different seeds but also with different **parameters**, so it seems to me that the OP never intended to share the generator among several threads :)

Comment: loreb is right, I don't want to share the generator among different threads.  I want to use one master generator to somehow seed different generators for each thread.  But when I say 'somehow' I'm cautious about seeding a MT from another MT lest that causes correlated output.  As far as I understand it, that's what the cited paper is about.

Comment: Also @loreb thanks for flagging up that parameters are different, I had wrongly equated them with seeds in my mind.